# How to get validations error messages in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm currently learning Ruby on rails with OpenClassrooms, and they are using that piece of code :

```
validates :name, presence: {
    message: "Give a name"
}
```

When I try to create an object without the name, I'm not getting any error. For example :

```
me = Person.new name:""
me.errors.to_hash
=> {}
```

With the same example (just not the same classes), OpenClassrooms get an error and I don't know why I don't get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are added to an object after validation. When you call `new`, you're not validating anything, so the object has no errors.

If you try and save it and then check the errors, you will get what you're looking for:

```
me = Person.new name:""
me.errors.to_hash
=> {}
```

```
me = Person.new name:""
me.save
=> false
me.errors.to_hash
=> ActiveModel::Errors...
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `me.validate` before checking the error object. You can also call `#valid?`.

```
me = Person.new name: ""
me.validate
me.errors.to_hash
=> { ... }
```

All saving methods call this `#validate` method internally, such as `#save` and `#save!`.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks ! OpenClassrooms didn't mention that (at least in my language)